# display a message whenever it finds nil when it's fetching database

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm facing a lot of issues with `nil`, it causes my app crash, and this one of issues I'm facing.

when the database is empty or equal to `nil`, it should tell me that you sould give my phone number when fetchPhoneNumber function finds database empty by displaying `UIAlertController`, but instead my app keep crashing.

all my attempts have failed, and below one of my attempts.

How I can fix this issue?

```
func fetchPhoneNumber(){

            do{

                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
                let phoneNumber = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

                if phoneNumber.count > 0{
                    for item in phoneNumber as! [NSManagedObject]{

                        number = item.valueForKey("phoneNumber") as? String

                        print(number!)

                    }
                }else{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning !", message: "You Need to Provide us With Your Phone Number", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
                        // ...
                    }
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
      presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }



            }catch{

               let error as NSError!
              print("error: \(error)")



    }

    phone = number!


}
```

Comment: Have you tries using breakpoints to see exactly where the error is occurring. Is is when the alert controller presents itself, before, or after? Try to get an error message from Xcode

Comment: Xcode tells me **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

however I'm not professional in iOS development yet

Comment: You should avoid implicitly unwrapped `Optional` and force unwrapping `Optional` whenever possible, they will be a likely cause of crashes down the line. Use regular `Optional` and test them while unwrapping.

Comment: Can you tell me which line that error is occurring on?

Comment: Is the error taking place while trying to assign `phone = number!`?

Comment: You need to either move the phone = number! Inside if condition or use if let number = number { phone = number }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
number = item.valueForKey("phoneNumber") as? String
```

you are assigning an **optional** string (`String?`) to the variable `number`. That means that this variable could now contain either a string, or `nil`, depending on if the `valueForKey` function returns a valid string or not.

Here

```
print(number!)
```

you force-unwrap this variable. So whenever it is nil (as in the condition above described) it will inevitably crash.

In Swift, you should use the following pattern to check for optional values:

```
if let validNumber = item.valueForKey("phoneNumber") as? String {
   print(validNumber)
}
else {
   // display alert
}
```

Comment: It's hardly a trick! This is a very common design pattern in Swift with deep implications of code safety and future compatibility. Programming with tricks will not get you very far.